# Detecting whether any text is encrypted or not

Tags: python-3.x, sha256

I am researching Cryptography. I wanted to know how one can differentiate between normal text & text encrypted by sha256 algorithm, either using python or using regular expressions.

Comment: i cannot conceive any useful application of regexen here. basically you should analyze the empirical bit/octet/word distribution over your sample. the more uniform it is, the more probable it is that you face encrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

SHA256 is not encryption algorithm, it's cryptographic hash function, so you cannot encrypt anything with it. What are you trying to distinguish?